# Hardware and Network issue related to NanoPi NEO Core2

Tags: video-streaming, linux-device-driver, logitech, srt, nanopi

I am developing a video streaming device that streams video to youtube.
For this, I am using NanoPi NEO Core2  as an SBC. It runs on
 "Base on UbuntuCore, Kernel: Linux-4.14" os version as mentioned on http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_NEO_Core2

Along with the SBC, I am using its shield to use peripheral ports like USB, ethernet, and debugging port.
For capturing video, I am using a Logitech c920 webcam.

Here I am facing two issues :

1. Hardware Issue
   When I connect Logitech C920 camera with NanoPi Neo Core2
   via mini shield, it freezes. I am unable to understand whether it is due to the power issue, or is it due to driver issues.
2. Network Issue
   I am using TP-LINK USB WIFI dongle ( TL- WN725N ) to connect to the high-speed internet. TPLINK dongle on its package, claims it can provide 150mps network speed. However, I am getting 5 to 8 Mbps, provided I have a 25 Mbps upload and download speed plan.

It also loses network connectivity frequently, which causes inconsistent video streaming. 
When I make a ping request to the SBC from a second computer within the same network, it gives loss -10-12% pings request.

Ethernet is also giving the same kind of result.
I am using NMCLI as a network manager. 
So is it because of nmcli or some other component creating an issue?
Please guide me in the case; I am doing anything wrong for connecting to the internet.
Does anyone experience the same kind of issue related to internet connectivity?

Mini shield: http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Mini_Shield_for_NanoPi_NEO_Core/Core2
TP-link: https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201810/20181022/TL-WN725N(EU&US)_3.0_datasheet.pdf
Logitech c 920 camera: https://www.logitech.com/en-in/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920

Answer (score 0):

From experience, lots of problems with SBCs are caused by the **power supply**. Possibly yours is not powerful enough. I assume you've not done **overclocking** (if such an option exists).

Here are some of the things I would try otherwise:

- use a **powered USB hub** rather than connect the peripherals to the USB ports on the shield.
- plug your peripherals one by one and see what happens
- leave `dmesg -w` running in a terminal window and look at the messages that show up when you plug a device
- inspect your log files eg `syslog`, they may contain some warnings or errors pertaining to your problem

If you are not sure whether this is a software (driver-related) or a hardware problem one thing you can do is prepare another SD card and try **another distribution** for your platform. I think you have at least three available from the maker: one based on Ubuntu, another based on Debian, and also one based on OpenWRT.

On NanoPi SBCs I also use Armbian which is ported to your model ([Link](https://www.armbian.com/nanopi-neo-core-2-lts/)), so it's another option for you.